# Installing OpenMP on Mac OS X 10.11

Tags: c, gcc, openmp

How can I get OpenMP to run on Mac OSX 10.11, so that I can execute scripts **via terminal**?

I have installed OpenMP: `brew install clang-omp`.

When I run, for example: `gcc -fopenmp -o Parallel.b Parallel.c` the following expression returns: `fatal error: 'omp.h' file not found`

I have also tried: `brew install gcc --without-multilib` but unfortunately this eventually returned the following (after first installing some dependencies):

```
The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
Error: Failed to download resource "mpfr--patch"
```

**Any recommended work arounds?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error enabling openmp - "ld: library not found for -lgomp" and Clang errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20321988/error-enabling-openmp-ld-library-not-found-for-lgomp-and-clang-errors)

Comment: I had this issue recently and fixed it by reinstalling clang-omp.

Comment: Um, if you want clang-omp, you need to invoke it, and not GCC

Comment: I'm currently trying this right now: https://github.com/DmitryUlyanov/Multicore-TSNE/issues/1

Comment: Here is how to force Apple's clang to support OpenMP:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47230419/3419533

Answer (score 45):

On a Mac, the command gcc is a symlink to Clang. So by calling

```
gcc -fopenmp -o your_program your_program.c
```

you are in fact using Clang, which until now has not had built-in support for OpenMP.

The newer versions of Clang do have support for OpenMP according to [this](http://blog.llvm.org/2015/05/openmp-support_22.html) post (where you can also find instructions on how to set it up).

On the other hand, if you still want to use gcc I can guide you through the steps that worked for me.

1. **Install gcc with brew.** The command you used should work:

   ```
   brew install gcc --without-multilib
   ```

   Alternatively, if brew says that you already have gcc installed you can try

   ```
   brew reinstall gcc --without-multilib
   ```

   As you may have noted, if you don't specify `--without-multilib` brew warns you that OpenMP may not work.
2. **Find the location of the newly installed gcc.**

   Brew appends the version number to gcc so that it does not conflict with the one installed by Command Line Tools. You will find the symlink in `usr/local/bin`.

   In my case it's

   ```
   usr/local/bin/gcc-5
   ```

   If you right-click and chose **"Show original**" it should show the `gcc-5` executable in `/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/5.3.0/bin/gcc-5` (version numbers may differ).
3. **Now you need to tell your system about it:**

   When calling a compiler your bash will look into `/usr/bin` by default and not in `/usr/local/bin`. You need to add this directory to your **$PATH**.

   This can be easily done with the command:

   ```
   PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
   ```
4. Now you should be able to compile with OpenMP enabled using:

   ```
   gcc-5 -fopenmp -o your_program your_program.c
   ```

**Remark:** `gcc-5` is the version I have installed, yours might differ.

Comment: Works for me, with the current version being `gcc-6`. Although if you're installing homebrew for the first time, shouldn't the $PATH modification be written into your .bashrc?

Comment: Where are the files? I get an error saying there is no input file

Comment: Which files are you refering to @SumNeuron? If you mean the ones in the last code line I gave the first "Parallel" is the name of the output executable and "Parallel.c" is the source to compile. Your terminal must be in the same directory as the "Parallel.c" file, else it won't find it.

Comment: @AlejandroDanielNoel my question is where do you get those files as the do not seem to be installed with gcc or  llvm

Comment: Parallel.c is the file with your code. The name is arbitrary albeit the context may have confused you. I changed the name to something more clear.

Comment: @LazerStackr You can type `echo $PATH` and enter, which will print the contents of the PATH variable. Copy-paste into a text editor and delete `/usr/local/bin:`, then copy the remaining string and do in the terminal `PATH=<your string>` (where you replace `<your string>`)

Comment: It worked for me.My gcc version is gcc-7. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just tried these steps and received the following notification from Homebrew: `Warning: gcc: this formula has no --without-multilib option so it will be ignored!`

Comment: @AlexJohnson comment on an answer below (https://stackoverflow.com/a/52508684/12109043) says "No need to add `--without-multilib` any more in 2019."

Answer (score 15):

- install clang-omp

  ```
   brew install clang-omp
  ```
- make sure you have installed the xcode command line tool

  ```
   xcode-select --install
  ```
- I actually had one error while running a sample openmp code

  ```
   /usr/local/opt/libiomp/include/libiomp/omp.h:139:21: error: expected ';' after top level declarator extern void   __ KAI_KMPC_CONVENTION kmp_set_stacksize_s        (size_t);
  ```
- Just remove one space that is present between __ and KAI from the file
- Now use the command

  ```
   clang-omp -fopenmp helloopenmp.c
  ```

and run the following code

```
    #include <omp.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main() {
        #pragma omp parallel
        printf("Hello from thread %d, nthreads %d\n", omp_get_thread_num(), omp_get_num_threads());
    }
```

- You should get output similar to this

  ```
   Hello from thread 3, nthreads 4
   Hello from thread 2, nthreads 4
   Hello from thread 0, nthreads 4
   Hello from thread 1, nthreads 4
  ```
- Worked on OS X 10.11.3 and with brew update dated 18th Feb 2016

Comment: clang-omp was deleted from homebrew/core in commit c57e307:
  clang-omp: migrate to boneyard
  Functionality is now available as part of LLVM in Homebrew.

Answer (score 8):

## macOS High Sierra Version 10.13.6 (17G65)

#### 1. Install gcc

`brew reinstall gcc --without-multilib`

#### 2. Compile

`gcc-8 -Wall -fopenmp your-parallel-program.c`

Notice the **gcc-8** watch the *version* brew installs, yours may be *gcc-7* or *gcc-9*

`==> Pouring gcc-8.2.0.high_sierra.bottle.1.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0: 1,495 files, 344.8MB`

That's it!

Comment: No need to add  `--without-multilib` any more in 2019.

Comment: invalid option: --without-multilib

Answer (score 8):

By default, GCC is using clang distribution. **Install GCC with Homebrew**. Once installed, you can compile the code **specifying the GCC version** installed by Homebrew and **adding the OpenMP flag**. A hello_world example is shown below:

1. brew install gcc
2. brew install libomp
3. brew info gcc

   gcc: stable **10.2.0** (bottled), HEAD

   GNU compiler collection
4. export OMP_NUM_THREADS=8
5. create hello.c

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>
int main(void){
    #pragma omp parallel 
    {
        printf("Hello World! \n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

7. gcc-10 -fopenmp hello.c -o hello
8. Execute: ./hello

```c
Hello World!
Hello World!
Hello World!
Hello World!
Hello World!
Hello World!
Hello World!
Hello World!
```

Comment: this does not add any value to existing and upvoted answers.

Answer (score 2):

1. Install gcc using brew.

   ```
   brew install gcc
   ```
2. Check gcc is installed.

   ```
   $which g++-7
   /usr/local/bin/g++-7
   ```
3. Change cmake cxx compiler.

   ```
   cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++-7
   make
   ```

Maybe this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
brew install cmake
brew install gcc --without-multilib
cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++-6 .. 
make -j
```

Answer (score 0):

After install gcc:

```
brew install gcc --without-multilib
```

and export PATH:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

You may need to export CC, which works for me:

```
export CC=/usr/local/bin/gcc
```

This maybe gcc-7, or whatever.