# Compiling C with OpenMP on my mac

Tags: c, macos, openmp

I am trying to compile the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>
int main(){
#pragma omp parallel
    {
        printf("%d\t%d\n",omp_get_thread_num(), omp_get_num_threads());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I tried both cc -o main.exe main.c and gcc -o main.exe main.c

Both ways I get "fatal error: 'omp.h' file not found"

So I downloaded the latest version of [OpenMP](https://www.openmprtl.org/download). Then in the terminal in the directory of the downloaded folder I typed make and then

```
sudo cp ./libiomp5.dylib /usr/lib/
```

but I am still having the same issue. How can I get this to compile?

Comment: You installed the _library_ but _not_ the development package [or whatever] that has `omp.h`. The web site should have better/exact details on how to do this.

Comment: Also on macOS you _can_ name your executables `.exe`, but you really _shouldn't_, or they might get associated with some application to be opened with.

Comment: I'll look around their site more and see what I can find, so far nothing. I'm doing .exe since it will eventually be put onto a cray machine and they examples given use .exe

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35134681/installing-openmp-on-mac-os-x-10-11

Answer (score 1):

You should guard the Openmp include and function calls with #if _OPENMP in order to support compiling without the openmp option  (gcc -fopenmp).