# MacOS Sierra xgboost jvm package installtion error

Tags: macos, scala, compiler-errors, jvm, xgboost

I am trying to build the osx sierra jvm package. However mvn -DskipTests install seems to fail and five the following error

```
 CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.7.2/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeDetermineCCompiler.cmake:48 (message):
  Could not find compiler set in environment variable CC:

  gcc-6.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)


CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/rjohri/xgboost/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
building Java wrapper
cd ..
mkdir -p build
cd build
cmake .. -DUSE_S3:BOOL=OFF -DUSE_OPENMP:BOOL=OFF -DPLUGIN_UPDATER_GPU:BOOL=OFF -DUSE_AZURE:BOOL=OFF -DUSE_HDFS:BOOL=OFF -DJVM_BINDINGS:BOOL=ON
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "create_jni.py", line 88, in <module>
    run("cmake .. " + " ".join(args) + maybe_generator)
  File "create_jni.py", line 51, in run
    subprocess.check_call(command, shell=True, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/rjohri/anaconda/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 540, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'cmake .. -DUSE_S3:BOOL=OFF -DUSE_OPENMP:BOOL=OFF -DPLUGIN_UPDATER_GPU:BOOL=OFF -DUSE_AZURE:BOOL=OFF -DUSE_HDFS:BOOL=OFF -DJVM_BINDINGS:BOOL=ON' returned non-zero exit status 1
[ERROR] Command execution failed.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine(ExecMojo.java:804)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine(ExecMojo.java:751)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute(ExecMojo.java:313)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] xgboost-jvm ........................................ SUCCESS [  4.922 s]
[INFO] xgboost4j .......................................... FAILURE [  1.799 s]
[INFO] xgboost4j-spark .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] xgboost4j-flink .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] xgboost4j-example .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.851 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-08-15T10:10:03+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 25M/391M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:exec (native) on project xgboost4j: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
```

I have updated my config.mk to include the gcc compiler

```
 # choice of compiler, by default use system preference.
 export CC = gcc-6
 export CXX = g++-6
```

But it seems like it needs me to change that some where else? I am not sure what other changes I need to do. I build the xgboost package with ./build.sh which ran successfully and installed the single thread version of xgboost. The failure happened when I tried to install the jvm package. Also make -j4 doesn't work for me as suggested in the documentation as it has issues with fopenmp and gives the following error

```
 Makefile:31: MAKE [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make] - checked OK
g++-6 -std=c++11 -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Iinclude   -Idmlc-core/include -Irabit/include -I/include -O3 -funroll-loops -msse2 -fPIC -fopenmp -o xgboost  build/cli_main.o build/learner.o build/logging.o build/c_api/c_api.o build/c_api/c_api_error.o build/common/common.o build/common/hist_util.o build/data/data.o build/data/simple_csr_source.o build/data/simple_dmatrix.o build/data/sparse_page_dmatrix.o build/data/sparse_page_raw_format.o build/data/sparse_page_source.o build/data/sparse_page_writer.o build/gbm/gblinear.o build/gbm/gbm.o build/gbm/gbtree.o build/metric/elementwise_metric.o build/metric/metric.o build/metric/multiclass_metric.o build/metric/rank_metric.o build/objective/multiclass_obj.o build/objective/objective.o build/objective/rank_obj.o build/objective/regression_obj.o build/predictor/cpu_predictor.o build/predictor/predictor.o build/tree/tree_model.o build/tree/tree_updater.o build/tree/updater_colmaker.o build/tree/updater_fast_hist.o build/tree/updater_histmaker.o build/tree/updater_prune.o build/tree/updater_refresh.o build/tree/updater_skmaker.o build/tree/updater_sync.o dmlc-core/libdmlc.a rabit/lib/librabit.a  -pthread -lm  -fopenmp 
make: g++-6: No such file or directory
ar crv lib/libxgboost.a 
g++-6 -std=c++11 -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Iinclude   -Idmlc-core/include -Irabit/include -I/include -O3 -funroll-loops -msse2 -fPIC -fopenmp -shared -o lib/libxgboost.dylib build/learner.o build/logging.o build/c_api/c_api.o build/c_api/c_api_error.o build/common/common.o build/common/hist_util.o build/data/data.o build/data/simple_csr_source.o build/data/simple_dmatrix.o build/data/sparse_page_dmatrix.o build/data/sparse_page_raw_format.o build/data/sparse_page_source.o build/data/sparse_page_writer.o build/gbm/gblinear.o build/gbm/gbm.o build/gbm/gbtree.o build/metric/elementwise_metric.o build/metric/metric.o build/metric/multiclass_metric.o build/metric/rank_metric.o build/objective/multiclass_obj.o build/objective/objective.o build/objective/rank_obj.o build/objective/regression_obj.o build/predictor/cpu_predictor.o build/predictor/predictor.o build/tree/tree_model.o build/tree/tree_updater.o build/tree/updater_colmaker.o build/tree/updater_fast_hist.o build/tree/updater_histmaker.o build/tree/updater_prune.o build/tree/updater_refresh.o build/tree/updater_skmaker.o build/tree/updater_sync.o dmlc-core/libdmlc.a rabit/lib/librabit.a -pthread -lm  -fopenmp 
make: g++-6: No such file or directory
make: *** [xgboost] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [lib/libxgboost.dylib] Error 1
ar: no archive members specified
usage:  ar -d [-TLsv] archive file ...
    ar -m [-TLsv] archive file ...
    ar -m [-abiTLsv] position archive file ...
    ar -p [-TLsv] archive [file ...]
    ar -q [-cTLsv] archive file ...
    ar -r [-cuTLsv] archive file ...
    ar -r [-abciuTLsv] position archive file ...
    ar -t [-TLsv] archive [file ...]
    ar -x [-ouTLsv] archive [file ...]
make: *** [lib/libxgboost.a] Error 1
```

Has anyone else faced any of these errors?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks! 
Rosh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I need to add the full path to my gcc compiler in the config file. It still gave a lot of warnings of not being able to run the open mp version so I am not sure if the multithreading version is actually enabled. I saw here: [Installing OpenMP on Mac OS X 10.11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35134681/installing-openmp-on-mac-os-x-10-11) that if gcc is already installed brew would require you to reinstall it to get the benefit of OpenMP. Will try that and update the answer here. For my current testing purpose though this is sufficient.